# Azure App Service Mobile App database synchronization failes if data is deleted

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm currently facing such a problem: I'm building an app using Xamarin and Azure App Service Mobile App as a cloud back-end. The thing is that if I delete some data from the corresponding table in DB hosted in Azure the next PullAsync call on mobile device fails because it tries to request the deleted record. Is there any way to synchronize the deletion of the records which happens first in Azure DB and then is pulled to the device?

The other way works smoothly: if I delete the record from the device, the corresponding record is deleted in Azure DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use soft delete by enabling is on your server for each `TableController` where you require it. Example here for a `TodoItem` `TableController`.

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
    DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request, enableSoftDelete: true);
}
```

More info [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/#the-deleted-field).

Comment: I was thinking of exactly the same way yesterday but hoped there is kind of solution with real deletion of the record. Alright, gonna mark this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: I've got another question related to this one: in EntityData class I've found an existing property named "Deleted", which I suppose can be used for soft deletion. The problem is that when I update it's value on mobile client the value doesn't get pushed to Azure and the next pull rewrites it to original value of false. Is there any way to use it or I should create some custom column?

Comment: What I've just found is that UpdateAsync for some reason doesn't write "Deleted" true to the local device storage, that's why it doesn't get synced to the Azure. No gonna find a solution for this problem

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to enable soft delete.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!
So, actually, my trick to update the property itself on the device doesn't work at all? Client API simply ignores it?